# Node.js - readstream returning ENOENT(errornr #4058)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, path

Im trying to display a html file from my node app. Heres my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require ('fs');
var path = require("path");
var filePath = path.normalize('/NodeJS/projects/test.html');   


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);    

    myReadStream.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('listening to port 3000');
```

I ran into the same problem earlier trying it with __dirname but It didnt work so I wanted to try using path.normalize.
Any pointers as to why this is not working. If I copy the dir from the console error into my explorer my test.html file opens.... The file is there. This must be some simple error but its killing me

Comment: I have nearly the same issue. But for me installed as a Windows service it fails to load the file. But usual with node server.js it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done in a simpler way.

I have my file in root folder

The `path.normalize()` method normalizes the given path, resolving `..` and `.` segments.

```
path.normalize('/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf
```

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");
var filePath = path.normalize('./index.html');

console.log(filePath)
//here you can include your HTML file
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: Looks much simpler indeed, and more like what I tried earlier. I still run into the same problem tho.

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\NodeJS\projects\test.html']

Comment: I mean I get that but how? test.html is inside the folder im navigating to. Im trying to understand this simple error but I dont see how its in the wrong path. If I open NodeJS/projects/ my test.html is literally there

Comment: Updated my answer for more info about normalize

Comment: I understand that. But since its in same folder as my app.js, a  simple path.normalize('./test.html) should do the trick right?. But it doesnt work. And I cannot wrap my head around why.